# Run Curl command to the Linux Server via php

Tags: php, linux, curl, ubuntu-14.04, wowza

I need to run the curl command to the Linux Wowza server and here is my Curl command which needs to be executed on the remote machine.

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/mystream/actions/restart --digest -u "user:password"
```

here is my converted curl to the php

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/mystream/actions/restart';
    $username = 'user';
    $pass = 'password';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "$username");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "$password")
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Any Tip will be helpful for me to figure this out. thanks in advance

Comment: What problem you're facing? Also don't add `"` for passing argument variable in `CURLOPT_USERNAME` and `CURLOPT_PASSWORD`

Comment: I want to confirm that this is the right translation of the curl command and i dont know if this is running or not

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to double quote your variables. So, for instance

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
```

Should be

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Second, you need a [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) at the end to actually make the CURL request do something

```
curl_exec($ch);
```

Finally, at the very end, make sure you can debug the response in some fashion

```
if($err = curl_error($ch)) echo 'Error: ' . $err;
```

Here's how to add your header

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/json', 'charset=utf-8'));
```

Your username/password setup is also wrong

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
```

Comment: Hey @Machavity 
thanks for your Time but i didnt get any response on the web page. so i dont know if this Command was successfully executed

Comment: Try echoing out the result of `curl_exec` then

Comment: `-X PUT --header 'Accept:application/json;`
don't i need to create  a curl varibale for this header in mycode

Comment: thank you machavity, I am still testing it and will mark it as answered when i am done

Comment: i could run the code but i get the follwoing waring ,.

`The request require user authentication`;
can you please help me

Comment: Your setup was wrong to authenticate. Added that to my answer

Comment: `$username = 'admin';
$pass = 'admin';
$ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/json', 'charset=utf-8'));
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );`

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $pass);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $res;
    if($err = curl_error($ch)) echo 'Error: ' . $err;
                curl_close ($ch);`

Comment: thats how the code look like but i am still having the same error

Comment: I have Added the new thread will be really helpful if you can also have a look on it

Comment: I have solved my Problem with User Authentication but now i got the another Issue `The method specified in the request is not allowed for the resource identified by the request URI`
can you please Lighten UP

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you make the request using Digest authentication, I'd include the following options in your php-curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

Secondly, ensure you include the following headers in your request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    ));
```

Then in your Wowza installation, confirm that your [Server.xml configuration](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?644-How-to-access-documentation-for-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-REST-API#config) under the RestInterface element has the following:

```
<AuthenticationMethod>digest</AuthenticationMethod>
```

Lastly, if you run into more trouble, you can add the following debug elements to further investigate any remaining issues with your request (Under Server->RestInterface->Properties):

```
        <Property>
            <Name>debugEnable</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
        </Property>
```